# Proxy websockets to a different port

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a web server that serves up static content with the following code:

```
// index.js
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const port=3000
const ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter').IpFilter
const ips = ['::1','::ffff:127.0.0.1','::ffff:103.146.251.86']

const app = express()

app.use(ipfilter(ips, { mode: 'allow' }))

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  extname: '.hbs',
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts')
}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.render('home', {

    cursor: request.query.cursor,
        screensaver: request.query.screensaver
  })
})

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

There is a mosquitto server on the same host that is serving up mqtt over web sockets. The browser side javascript sets up the mqtt connection to port 9001. Is there a way to proxy that websocket connection through the server in the code above so that they can share the same port?

I am not familiar with setting up proxies with nodejs and express and I cannot seem to find this use case by googling. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#:~:text=Protocol%20handshake,-To%20establish%20a&text=The%20handshake%20starts%20with%20an,connections%20on%20the%20same%20port.): The handshake starts with an HTTP request/response, allowing servers to handle HTTP connections as well as WebSocket connections on the same port. Once the connection is established, communication switches to a bidirectional binary protocol which does not conform to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done before asking the question? The first hit when searching for "express js WebSockets proxy" looks very relevant https://gist.github.com/hhanh00/ddf3bf62294fc420a0de